Нужна помощь в выводе времени в формате Часы/Минуты/Секунды
Доброго времени суток, у меня возникла не большая проблема, я имею количество продукции в переменной production, и мне нужно узнать сколько времени займет производство этого количества продукции (это постоянно целые числа но они постоянно разные могут быть)
Вот мой не большой вариант, он работает, но у меня постоянно отображается только что-то одно или секунды или минуты или же часы
# Время производства 1 материала в секундах
        production_time_per_unit_seconds = 48

        # Общее время производства в секундах
        total_production_time_seconds = production * production_time_per_unit_seconds
        total_production_time = f"Время производства: {total_production_time_seconds} сек."

        if total_production_time_seconds >= 60:
            total_production_time_minutes = total_production_time_seconds / 60
            total_production_time = f"Время производства: {total_production_time_minutes} мин."
            if total_production_time_minutes >= 60:
                total_production_time_hours = total_production_time_minutes / 60
                total_production_time = f"Время производства: {total_production_time_hours} час."

        print(total_production_time)

Я хочу сделать чтобы было отображено так:
Время производства займет: 12 часов 45 минут 11 секунд (это я пример привел как я хочу чтобы отображалось время) но к сожалению я не много не пойму как это реализовать, буду благодарен за полный ответ так как хочу это понять, а не просто списать готовое решение.

Вам понадобится оператор взятия остатка от деления % 60
